# Login con contraseña encriptada Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

estoy realizando un sistema de login con contraseña encriptada... Esta conformado por nombre de usuario y la contraseña, el cual me funciona sin encriptacion de esta manera:

```php
if($user->nom_us == $request->usuario && $user->clave == $request->password){
```

y a la hora de cambiar a la contraseña encriptada lo intento hacer de esta manera:

```php
if($user->nom_us == $request->usuario) && (password_verify($user->clave == $request->password)){
```

la cual arroja error claro esta. Como se estructuraría para que lograra ingresar el usuario?

Comment: El llamado a `password_verify` recibe 2 parametros string... password y hash... solo estás pasando un valor (y además es booleano). Podría ser eso... o depronto también podría ser problema de como estás almacenando la clave en `$user->clave`

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.